# Javascript-modules and Web-Component

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'd like to define a Webcomponent in a Javascript-Module and call a method of this component.

The browser raises an Javascript-error: "helloworld" is not a function.

Strange: If I load the Javascript-File "normally" and not as a module, the function is called.

How can I make it run as a Javascript-Module?

This is the JavaScript-Module main.js:

```
customElements.define('hello-world', 
  class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {     
    helloworld() {
        console.log("Hello World");
    }
});
```

This is the HTML-Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
    <script>
      var instance = document.querySelector( 'hello-world' );
      instance.helloworld();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Loading Javascript with

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

works.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is: Modules are alway loaded asyc and are alway executed after the DOM is loaded.
Therefore the Web-Component is not yet defined when it's instanciated in HTML.

This code works, since the inline-module is executed **after** the extern module.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>simple demo</title>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
    <script type="module" >
      var  instance = document.querySelector('hello-world');
      instance.helloworld();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```